# Быстрый поиск по базе

Tags: node.js, nginx, nosql, sql

Есть цель, сделать "живой поиск" по некоторой базе аудио-записей. Все пишется в связке nodeJS + nginx. Проект только начал делать, не определился еще с выбором базы данных(SQL, nosql, memory).

В базе могут находится несколько (десятков, сотен) тысяч записей. У каждой записи могут быть поля:"name, autor, жанр, стиль" и т.п. И некоторые другие параметры - популярность, популярность среди друзей, популярность по интересам. На данный момент нахожусь в тупике с выбором базы данных, где собственно хранить данные о записях и главное как сделать супер-быстрый поиск по ним. Условие, то что база не должна быть встроенная в проект, будет находится на отдельном сервере.

Скажите свои мысли об этом, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я, как человек заболевший неизлечимой болезнью под названием nosql головного мозга, использовал-бы mongodb, кстати файлы хранил-бы в ней-же.

#####[mongoDB gridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS)

Comment: @AlexWindHope хранить файлы в бд? Да вы точно больны. Люди наоборот стараются кешировать, сокращают время доступа. А вы в базу советуете пихать их, увеличивая время доступа и общую нагрузку на систему. Для файлов есть уже база данных - это файловая система.

Comment: @AlexWindHope gridFS топорное решение, производительность падает. А масштабируемость должна нормальными средствами организовываться, а не костылями.

Comment: @lampa - например?

Comment: @AlexWindHope например я был на я.субботнике, у них по моему zookeeper

Comment: @lampa и чем это лучше?

Comment: @AlexWindHope скажу так: его используют профессионалы, в отличие от тех, кто использует предложенную вами :-)

Comment: @lampa - это ваш единственный аргумент?

> в отличие от тех, кто использует предложенную вами

Вы в этом уверенны?

Answer (score 2):

Для реального проекта выбирайте то, что знаете лучше. Для поиграться можно чтото новое выбрать.

Но учитывая "У каждой записи могут быть поля:"name, autor, жанр, стиль" и т.п. И некоторые другие параметры - популярность, популярность среди друзей, популярность по интересам.", стоит выбрать чтонибудь из SQL.

В принципе и mysql подойдет.. можно и pgSQL